# Pycharm second window when debuggin

Tags: pycharm

When I start debugging the second window pops up so it's really annoying. how can I turn it off?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are stepping into a library script.

In your settings go to `Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Stepping`.

Check  `Do not step into library scripts`.

If the script is part of your project, but you do not want to step into it, you can check `Do not step into scripts` and provide a file you do not want to step into.